# Words (especially homographs or homonyms) with different inflection

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for words (especially homographs or homonyms of the same word class) that differ in their inflection?

- The Latin *[ēdūcō](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/educo#Latin)* whose present infinitive is *[ēducere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/educere#Latin)* (“to lead forth, to erect”) or *[ēducāre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/educare#Latin)* (“to bring up; to educate, to train; to produce”).
- The Icelandic *[hór](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%B3r#Icelandic)* meaning a “hook for a pot, an earmark for sheep” for [one declension](http://bin.arnastofnun.is/leit.php?id=404033), “adultery” for a [second declension](http://bin.arnastofnun.is/leit.php?id=1644) and a “lover of a married woman” for a [third declension](http://bin.arnastofnun.is/leit.php?id=5361).

I can't think of any English examples off the top of my head.

Comment: Another example in Spanish, esta (this) and está (it is).  Interesting question +1

Comment: For some speakers English *hang* works: the picture was *hung*, but the man was *hanged*. For some the noun *mouse* works: the plural is *mice* for the animal and *mouses* for the computer peripheral. For some *appendix* works: books have *appendices*, but people have *appendixes*.

Comment: I'm sure there are a vast number of such words, as @Brian's comment suggests. I'd say *worked* is much the same, in that *wrought* rarely occurs except preceded by *over* or followed by *iron*. But it's an open-ended question which should either be community wiki or closed. I'm voting to close, because my understanding is we don't want wiki to be a general dumping ground.

Comment: ...also, *homographs, homonyms,* and *different inflections* are three radically different ways that "different" words can be related. Even adding a plural "s" to a word is an *inflection*, for example, and many, many words have specific meanings only with certain inflections. If I could vote to close *twice*, I surely would.

Comment: Isn't this a general linguistics question rather than an English one?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I don't think it's really a question at all. It's just an observation that by the very nature of language, related forms of some words come to diverge in meaning. And that *different* words sometimes have the same appearance and/or sound as other words that they're not historically related to. In specific cases these effects may be interesting, but I honestly fail to see how a general discussion of the process, or examples thereof, would fit in with EL&U's basic objectives.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be [heteronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_%28linguistics%29)?

> words that are written identically but have different pronunciations and meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Homograph is one of two or more words that have the same spelling but differ in origin, meaning, and sometimes pronunciation, such as fair (pleasing in appearance) and fair (market) or wind (wĭnd) and wind (wīnd) or trunk (a part of elephant) and trunk  (a storage chest).